# pandas dataframe - remove columns where all values satisfy condition

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns. Single level indexes throughout.

I was hoping to drop the columns where all values in the column ==0

I am able to do it by looping over each column, testing and creating a boolean array.
Then I transpose, slice and transpose back

BUT

I have to think there is better way.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a boolean condition to make a mask and then call `any` and pass param `axis=0` to drop the columns that are all `NaN`, the `any` call will create a boolean series which you use to select the columns where all the values are not `NaN`:

```
In [18]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5), 'b':0,'c':np.random.randn(5),'d':0, 'e':np.arange(5)})
df
Out[18]:
          a  b         c  d  e
0 -0.546906  0  0.235070  0  0
1  0.260935  0  0.650391  0  1
2  0.419727  0 -1.002794  0  2
3 -0.283556  0  0.668378  0  3
4  0.924392  0 -1.297040  0  4
In [28]:

df[df.columns[(df!=0).any(axis=0)]]
Out[28]:
          a         c  e
0 -0.546906  0.235070  0
1  0.260935  0.650391  1
2  0.419727 -1.002794  2
3 -0.283556  0.668378  3
4  0.924392 -1.297040  4
In [27]:

(df!=0).any(axis=0)
Out[27]:
a     True
b    False
c     True
d    False
e     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: @DSM as ever you're right, I've changed it to use `any` which does the correct thing now

Comment: This helped me remove all columns where no value meets threshold in pandas data frame

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b': [0,0], 'c': [3,4], 'd': [0, 0]})
df[[col for col in df if ~df[col].eq(0).all()]]
Out[11]: 
   a  c
0  1  3
1  2  4
```